# Class name of Default - a code smell?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am struggling with the design of part of my application and am in a constant state of changing things back and forth.

Currently I have an abstract class from which i derrive specialised class types but I do need a general class type which applies to most scenarios.

This class is currently named Default, though I am wondering if this is a code smell of any sorts or whether it is acceptable.

The structure looks like this (this is hugely simplified):

```
AbstractPageType
    DefaultPageType
    SmallPageType
    LargePageType
```

Comment: How about a class named Value?

Comment: Perhaps this is a better fit for CodeReview.SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Default` is different than `DefaultPageType`

In my opinion, `DefaultPageType` is a perfectly fine name.

However, how does Default, Small and Large page types all differ?

Wouldn't it make more sense to have:

```
AbstractPage:
   DefaultPage:
       SmallPage:
       LargePage:
```

And have Large and Small both specialize Default.

Comment: If thats the case why have the abstract class?  Either remove or replace with an interface?

Comment: Good point; since java has interfaces, it's a better idea to remove "AbstractPage" since it's a meaningless class to any user of your lib.